# How to prevent duplicate entries while refreshing?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, post-redirect-get

I have an `index.jsp` page where I have a form where the user enters some data that gets stored in the database using a Controller servlet.

I want to display the same page (`index.jsp`) with that form after entering the data in the database. Also, I want to display all the entries that the user entered in the database.

I tried using the `forward()` method of `RequestDispatcher`. It works fine (meaning I am able to display that same form again and also display all the data entered by that user below the form using JSTL).

But the problem is whenever the user presses the `Refresh or F5` button, all the previous data also gets entered in the database and as I am displaying all the data, and that duplicate entries also come up.

I thought of using the POST-REDIRECT-GET pattern, but the problem is when I redirect I don't get those data to be displayed using JSTL.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *I thought of using POST-REDIRECT-GET pattern but the problem is when I redirect I don't get those data to be displayed using JSTL.*

Just send a request parameter along identifying the information you'd like to display in the new GET request.

```
// ...
Long id = dataService.save(data);
// ...
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/index?editId=" + id);
```

and then in the [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) which is mapped on an URL pattern of `/index`

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Long editId = Long.valueOf(request.getParameter("editId")); // Handle nullcheck yourself.
    Data editData = dataService.find(editId);
    request.setAttribute("editData", editData); // For the edit form.
    List<Data> allData = dataService.list();
    request.setAttribute("allData", allData); // For the table/list of all data.
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Balus I think this is a good solution I will definitely try this and let you know.

Answer (score 5):

I would add an invisible ID to the page. If the data is new to the database (ID = unknown), insert and create an ID and update the page with the ID. That way you know if it is a ID != unknown, and you don't have to do an insert. And if the data hasn't changed, you don't even have to do an update...

Comment: I'm afraid, I'm not experienced with servlets. What I wrote was a typical scenario that I am facing using plain old Java and databases. I guess you could adopt that approach. What I cannot tell is if servlet technology has some built-in feature doing this for you.

Comment: Fildor's suggestion is the way to do it. Include the database ID of your record in the page in a hidden field. If the user hasn't submitted the data yet this should be -1 or 0. When you process the request to insert the data get the database ID of the newly inserted row and include that in the page next time. If the user submits the form again use the ID to update the details, which is what they would expect. BTW, use a POST not a GET in your form - the user will then be alerted that the data will be resubmitted if they refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest solution

```
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<%!
//This List is just for demonstration purposes
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
%>
<%
if(request.getParameter("name")!=null ){
    names.add(request.getParameter("name"));
    session.setAttribute("nameList", names);
    //Here you put your database insert code

    //Whenever the code execution reaches this line , 
    //then it means that you have a new page submission
    //and not a refresh or f5 case

    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
}
%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="index.jsp" method="post">
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
        </form>
        <p>
            <table>
                <c:forEach items="${nameList}" var="element">    
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name:  <c:out value="${element}"/> </td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </table>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The trick lies with the `response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");`. This makes `null` all request parameters. If an `f5` or `refresh` is hit, then the `if` is never executed. If a normal submit is the case, then the `if` is executed and you call the  `response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");`.

In summary, all you really need to do is:

1) Check `if(request.getParameter("name")!=null )`

2) If above is true then do database inserts

3) If above is true then `response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");`

**UPDATE**

```
if(request.getParameter("name")!=null ){
    DbUtility.addNameToDb(request.getParameter("name"));
    ArrayList<String> currentList = DbUtility.getAllNamesFromDb();
    session.setAttribute("nameList", currentList);
    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
}
```

You just have to implement these 2 methods. The `addNameToDb(String)` will make the `insert` in your database. And the `getAllNamesFromDb()` will return an `ArrayList<String>` Object that will represent on the entries from your database. (And you no longer need the `names` list introduced before in my first answer)

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, but I also want to add entries to the database.What I want to do is suppose I made 1 entry using the form in the database, then all my entries(assume name is the primary key) should be displayed below the same form that I used. It is displaying fine for now but when I hit refresh I find the duplicate entries also.

Comment: I will try it but I don't want to use `session` scope for storing my data it needs to be in `request` scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think PRGP (Post Redirect Get Pattern) is the way to go for this. If you're using Spring Web Flow it has a FlashScope where you can put the data that you want to be retained after the Post-get-redirection. You can retain more than just an edit Id using this approach.