# hyperlink redirect to another JSP

Tags: java, jsp, redirect

I have a hyperlink for one of the column which looks like this.

```
<td align="ct"><a href="<%=getContext()%>/otp/taxView.do?call=first&taxId=<bean:write name="otping" property="taxNumber" />"><bean:write name="otping"
                                property="taxNumber" /></a>
                        </td>
```

Can I use the same to redirect to a different uri? When I google for redirect there are options to move action to controller and use sendRedirect and meta-refresh. Will the above work? or should I use a different method?

Comment: What would you like to achieve? This code just produces a uri, you can produce different uri, but none of them will redirect automatically browser to different page. However when you click the link, you will go to desired page.

Comment: What you're using is a link that the user must click on. Redirect means that the address is changed without the user having to click anything. So its not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @Gas and @ developerwjk.. Thanks for your replies. My requirement is that when I click the link to should be redirected to a different uri. RightNow its /otp/taxView.do? and I would want to change them to /taxFilings/Annuity.do? or something like that. But the customer used the word redirect to a different uri. But what I infer from your replies is redirect happens automatically without the user needing to click a button. But my requirement is on a hyperlink click. So im assuming that a href would itself take me to a different uri. Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: Do you mean you want to do the redirect after the link. User clicks link to taxView.do, and inside taxView.do there's a `response.sendRedirect("Annuity.do");` so there's both a click and a redirect?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = 'Different uri'
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is referred as post-redirect-get pattern. You send POST to one uri, it performs action and then returns 'redirect' to the browser, which presents result page. This prevents re-posting when user is going through back/forward in history. This requires using respnse.sendRedirect(), as it looks like using Struts it can be defined via configuration.

Check here for more details:

[post-redirect-get-prg-pattern-in-servlet-jsp](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/java/design-patterns/post-redirect-get-prg-pattern-in-servlet-jsp/)
[post-redirect-get-when-passing-data-to-the-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686700/post-redirect-get-when-passing-data-to-the-form)
[Implement-Post-Redirect-Struts](http://www.coderanch.com/t/537018/Struts/Implement-Post-Redirect-Struts)