# servlet inserts duplicate data as many times the page got refreshed

Tags: html, servlets

I have one html page named "RegistrationForm.html" whose action is a Servlet named "InsertRecord". This servlet reads form data and inserts record in database and after inserting it forwards to a "welcome.html" page. My problem is this that after submitting form i come to welcome page but as many times i refreshes this welcome page, that many times duplicate data gets stored in database.
Can somebody help me to over come this problem.

RegistrationForm.html(html page)

```
<form action="InsertRecord" method='get'>
        User Name <input type='text' name='uname'/>
        <br/>
        Contact <input type='tel' name='contact'/>
        <br/>
        <input type='submit'/>
    </form>
```

InsertRecord.java(servlet)

```
{
    String userName = request.getParameter("uname");
        String contact = request.getParameter("contact");

        //code for DB Connection
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databasename=sushil;user=sa; password=MultiMetal");

        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate("insert into tblUser (UserName, Contact) values('" + userName + "','" + contact + "')");

        request.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome.html").forward(request, response);
```

}

Welcome.html page contains only welcome message

Comment: i would like to u check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724526/how-to-prevent-duplicate-entries-while-refreshing

Comment: it would help if you post your code, so people here could find out where you got it wrong

Answer (score 0):

You must put check for duplicate data in your servlet. There may be identical data in your database e.g. user email, telephone number, name with date of birth etc. first check if record already exists then display you already registered else insert record

Please always write data sending method in html `<form>` tag e.g.

```html
<form action="InsertRecord" method=get or post>
```

**UPDATE**
So from comments I believe you need to change this:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome.html").forward(request, response);
```

TO

```
response.sendRedirect("/welcome.html");
```

Comment: Hi Ghayel - I think, Your answer is wrong. Instead of checking duplicate, we need to prevent submitting data while refreshing. Data should be submitted only when user submit a form or click a submit button.

Comment: Can you please share your code. I thought user once clicked submit button and thereafter on refresh this form inserting again. please share your code to trace the route cause in this case

Comment: Sushil add method=get or method=post in html

Comment: I have tried both the method but still same problem. As many times i refresh the welcome.html page that many times duplicate data gets inserted in database

Comment: what is your servlet method. I mean its doGet or doPost?

Comment: One more thing you are not pressing submit button and only refreshing page then data is inserted or you are pressing submit button and thereafter you are refreshing page??

Comment: 1. netbeans IDE creates one method named processRequest(req, res) which is internally called from both the method i.e. doGet and doPost. like this:

 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{

}

 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
 processRequest(request, response);
}

 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
 processRequest(request, response);
}

Comment: 2. after entering details i click on submit button then data gets saved in database and i am forwarded to welcome.html page and as many times i refreshes that welcome page, that many duplicate data gets stored in database. It happens because in address bar the URL is still "InsertRecord" (it should be welcome.html) thats why refresh happens on "InsertRecord" and not  on "welcome.html"

Answer (score 0):

I used response.sendRedirect("welcome.html") instead of forward method.